# How to allow exceptions to \MakeLowercase or alternative macro

Tags: definition

Please see attached mwe.  How can we optionally protect characters or words from the effect of `\MakeLowercase{}`?

```
\documentclass{article}%

\def\thestring{A Pacific hurricane is a mature tropical cyclone that develops within the northeastern and central {P}acific {O}cean}

\begin{document}

\noindent\thestring.\\

{\noindent}The expedition leader explained that \MakeLowercase{\thestring}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: See the textcase package, it has a similar macro which supports a NoCaseChange macro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the features of `\text_lowercase:n` of `expl3`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Lower}{m}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl { \K }
  \text_lowercase:n { #1 }
  \group_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\K}{m}{#1}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\teststring{A Pacific hurricane is a mature tropical cyclone that
  develops within the northeastern and central \K{Pacific Ocean}}

\begin{document}

\teststring.

The expedition leader explained that \Lower{\teststring}.

\end{document}
```

By itself `\K` does nothing else than deliver its argument, but it will do so only after `\text_lowercase:n` has done its job; adding `\K` to the list of excluded commands, does the trick.

The operation

```
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl { \K }
```

could be also done once and for all:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Lower}{m}
 {
  \text_lowercase:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\K}{m}{#1}
\tl_put_right:Nn \l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl { \K }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

You could also use `K{P}acific \K{O}cean`.

Comment: Currently exploring proposed solution, where is `\l_text_case_exclude_arg_tl` defined?

Comment: Compiles with `article.cls`.  When not using `article.cls`, which dependencies are required?

Comment: @JohnChris It's a token list variable provided by the `expl3` kernel. This should be independent of the document class.

Comment: Thanks @egreg.  Updated system, now all good.